# Disable system cooling

Tags: windows-10, cpu, 64-bit, cooling

When my PC gets a bit hot [?] I get lowered performance. To be honest, I don't really understand the reason my PC can run super-fast and after 15 seconds of stress it's running super-slow. It's a trouble for me, because I can't play any more demanding games. When I was going around through system power options, I saw the thing called System Cooling Policy.

Both, `active` and `passive` options for it don't satisfy me, because I get the same output every time. Also, I spotted, that my CPU speed is bound to `47%` during this state. Never less, never more.

[image: http://imgur.com/fcyhASp] 
(note the stress section, the `47%` section and the stress section again. It's going from `100%` to `47%` and after 15 seconds back to `100%`).

It's happening only durring stress and it goes on even with low demanding games like `League of Legends`. Also, it's happening to me ALWAYS durring recording stuff with `Action!` and sometimes durring Video editing using `Sony Vegas`.

I can't understand what's this problem related to, because my PC is running quiet and cool. Temperatures don't go high. None of those even go over **45*C.** I've got a really big and effective radiator on my CPU and a couple of working fans. I'm checking temperatures with `SpeedFan`.

Also, I wanted to mess a bit with BIOS settings. I tried disabling `AMD Cool'n'Quiet` thingy, and for once it worked. I could really work on my PC, record, play, everything! Now, after a couple of days it's back again.

Here are my specs:

- **CPU**: AMD FX-4100
- **GPU**: GeForce 550TI
- **RAM**: 8GB DDR3
- **SSD**: Intel SSDSA2CW080G3 (80GB)
- **HDD**: WDC WD2500JS-60NCB1 (250GB)
- **OS**: Windows 10 64bit

Also, I'm using 2 displays. One is `1980x1080` and the other is `1600x900`

UPDATE:
Here's something weird. Temperatures of CPU are being displayed correctly and are around 40*C-50*C during high stress. When the weird cycle begins, the temperatures are going.. -150*C!

[image: http://imgur.com/MaJLM6x]

I think the thermometer on my CPU is malfunctioning. Any ideas of going around it?

Comment: CPUs are "mercurial" in that their temperature rises in fractions of a second, and generally cools down almost as quickly, unless your cooling is malfunctioning. This is because we are working on a very very small scale. you may have dramatically different temps in locations a millimeter or less apart. Hard disks on the other extreme end, heat very slowly, and stay warm for hours. You cooling strategy shoudl keep your CPU well under the point where you experience slowdowns, but instead allow the CPU to evacuate heat very quickly, so that when the activity dies down, temp drops off in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

`70°` is too hot for an AMD chip.
Also youre saying that you have a "big and effective radiator" on your CPU.

If your temperatures are still this high, there is something wrong with your cooler installation.

> AMD’s specification of 61°C-70°C is for maximum allowed case temperature (a thermocouple measurement taken on top of the CPU lid); however, one will be measuring CPU core/junction temperature with a utility such as SpeedFan, etc. As there is significant thermal resistance between the CPU lid and core/junction (due to TIM1, etc), the core temperature will be much higher than the case temperature. Therefore, it is possible to reach the recommended ~80-85°C average core temperature, while not exceeding the AMD max case temp of 61-70°C.

Comment: Previously I had an Intel CPU and it could go up to 90*C without any problem. I'm not asking for solutions of cooling down my PC or upgrading fans, but I need to disable the SYSTEM cooling which is slowing down my PC.

Comment: Updating the question, I found out something really weird.

Comment: If you disable system cooling, you could risk, damaging your CPU.  If you disable it, your computer will also automatically shutdown at some point, not allowing you to save any work.

Comment: Nobody even bothers to take a look at my -180*C temperatures? Seriously?